# How to generate unique 6 digit code

Tags: php, string, random

I want to generate 6 digit unique code but i want first 3 are alphabets and last 3 are numbers like below example..

```
AAA111
ABD156
DFG589
ERF542...
```

Please help to create code with above combinations..

below is my code..

```
public function generateRandomString()  {
        $characters = '1234567890';
        $length = 6;
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
        return $randomString;
    }
```

Comment: You've already accepted the answer, but I've updated it to be a bit more efficient.

Comment: You may want to use [`Random::alphaUppercaseString(3)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Random) concatenated (with a dot) with `Random::intBetween(100, 999)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the first 3 chars as letters and the last 3 chars as number? Then you should handle them both sepperatly.

```
function genRandStr(){
  $a = $b = '';

  for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
    $a .= chr(mt_rand(65, 90)); // see the ascii table why 65 to 90.    
    $b .= mt_rand(0, 9);
  }

  return $a . $b;
}
```

You can also use function arguments to add dynamicness and for a random order you can do the following:

```
// PHP >= 7 code
function genRandStr(int $length = 6, string $prefix = '', string $suffix = ''){
  for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
    $prefix .= random_int(0,1) ? chr(random_int(65, 90)) : random_int(0, 9);
  }

  return $prefix . $suffix;
}
```

Use [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) for PHP version < 7, otherwise [`random_int()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) is recommended.

You still need to check for possible collisions though and put it in a while loop.

Comment: I kind of like this approach... One way to perhaps make it more readable is to use `chr(mt_rand(ord('A'), ord('Z')))` when generating the letters.

Comment: In essence, that would just add 6 additional function calls but would make the code more readable to the human eye.

Answer (score 4):

```
function generateRandomString()  {
    $letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $digits = '1234567890';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $letters[rand(0, strlen($letters) - 1)];
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $digits[rand(0, strlen($digits) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ec0b494c4e08ab220fe7601504c8611459690c33

Comment: Because I appreciate sportsmanship, +1. Your code does the job still is efficient.

Answer (score 1):

please check below code:

```
<?php
    $string1 = str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
    $random1 = substr($string1,0,3);
    $string2 = str_shuffle('1234567890');
    $random2 = substr($string2,0,3);

    echo $random = $random1.$random2;
?>
```

Comment: One potential downside to using this approach is that there won't be any repeated letters or digits.